# Email Validation Problem

Tags: javascript

I am Validating email address of a User. But problem appeared when i call that function and form is submitted without validating email address. Please tell me whats wrong with that code.

```
function validateEmail(fld) {
var error="";
var tfld = trim(fld.value);                   
var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/ ;
var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;
if (fld.value == "") {
    fld.style.background = 'Pink';
    error = "You didn't enter an email address.\n";
} else if (!emailFilter.test(tfld)) {         
    fld.style.background = 'Pink';
    error = "Please enter a valid email address.\n";
} else if (fld.value.match(illegalChars)) {
    fld.style.background = 'Pink';
    error = "The email address contains illegal characters.\n";
} else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error; }
```

Comment: Please tell *me* (and everyone) what the problem was (i.e. what error message you got, or what output you expected and how the actual output was different).  In particular, if the form is submitting without validating, surely your problem lies with the *form* and not with this function, unless I've misunderstood?

Comment: if i leave the field empty then it tells "You didn't enter an email address" but when i enter illegal chars then it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always return true or false:-

```
 function validateEmail(fld) {
    var error="";
    var tfld = trim(fld.value);                   
    var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/ ;
    var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;
    if (fld.value == "") {
        fld.style.background = 'Pink';
        error = "You didn't enter an email address.\n";
    } else if (!emailFilter.test(tfld)) {         
        fld.style.background = 'Pink';
        error = "Please enter a valid email address.\n";
    } else if (fld.value.match(illegalChars)) {
        fld.style.background = 'Pink';
        error = "The email address contains illegal characters.\n";
    } else {
        fld.style.background = 'White';
    }
    if (error == '')
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
      alert(error);
      return false;
    }
```

}

Call your function like this:-

```
 <input type="submit" onsubmit="return validateEmail(email.val)">
```

Comment: And always perform the final validation server-side. Don't rely on users having JavaScript turned on! (And don't rely on users actually using your HTML code to send the data, either …)

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateEmail(fld) {
var error="";
var tfld = trim(fld.value);                   
var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/ ;
var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;
if (fld.value == "" || fld.value.length == 0) {
    fld.style.background = 'Pink';
    error = "You didn't enter an email address.\n";
} else if (!emailFilter.test(tfld)) {         
    fld.style.background = 'Pink';
    error = "Please enter a valid email address.\n";
} else if (fld.value.match(illegalChars)) {
    fld.style.background = 'Pink';
    error = "The email address contains illegal characters.\n";
} else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error; }
```

try that!